# Set Default Filter to Reactable Table in R

Tags: r, reactable

Reactable package for R has introduced the capability to custom filter columns.

[Reactable Custom Filtering](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/custom-filtering.html)

There are some great examples at the the above link of how to add a drop down (select) list to a specific column however I'm finding it difficult to work out how to add a default filtered value on table load.

See the below example (modified from the aforementioned link), how would I have the table load with column `Manufacturer` filtered by the value `Acura`?

```
library(reactable); library(htmltools)

data <- MASS::Cars93[, c("Manufacturer", "Model", "Type", "Price")]

reactable(
  data,
  filterable = TRUE,
  columns = list(
    Manufacturer = colDef(
      filterInput = function(values, name) {
        tags$select(
          onchange = sprintf("Reactable.setFilter('cars-select', '%s', event.target.value)", name),
          lapply(unique(values), tags$option),
          style = "width: 100%; height: 28px;"
        )
      }
    )
  ),
  defaultPageSize = 5,
  elementId = "cars-select"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a reactable native way to set the initial filter, but I've been setting the filter on document load through jquery without issue. You can include the following through a `js` code chunk or `htmltools::tags$script(...)`

```js
$(document).ready(() => Reactable.setFilter('cars-select', 'Manufacturer', "Acura"));
```

I believe some cases the table will not be available at document ready time, so a solution with `htmlwidgets::onStaticRenderComplete(...)` may be better, but I wasn't able to get this to work in knitted documents (it works interactively in RStudio for me though).

```
library(reactable); library(htmltools)

data <- MASS::Cars93[, c("Manufacturer", "Model", "Type", "Price")]

tagList(
  reactable(
    data,
    filterable = TRUE,
    columns = list(
      Manufacturer = colDef(
        filterInput = function(values, name) {
          tags$select(
            onchange = sprintf("Reactable.setFilter('cars-select', '%s', event.target.value)", name),
            lapply(unique(values), tags$option),
            style = "width: 100%; height: 28px;"
          )
        }
      )
    ),
    defaultPageSize = 5,
    elementId = "cars-select"
  ),
  # The added code chunk
  htmlwidgets::onStaticRenderComplete("Reactable.setFilter('cars-select', 'Manufacturer', 'Acura')")
)
```

There's some helpful discussion in the [`onStateChange()`](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/javascript-api#reactable-onstatechange) section of the javascript-api documentation in reactable about adding javascript code after rendering as well.